# Matlab draw 3D stacked figure use bar3() for multiple variables

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure, stacked

I am trying to use `bar3(X,'stacked')` to create a stacked figure as below example:
[image]

However, so far my figure looks like this:

[image]

The data I am using are as follows.
My goal is to create the stack figure for each array.

```
airQ_2015 =

   13.1229   12.1409
   17.0748   17.4414
   13.1405   14.5241
   13.4213   22.0633
   19.4967   13.3508
   21.0111   14.7329
   12.9777   14.6583
   13.2616   17.2134
   13.8593   17.3916
   17.1445   22.6090
   11.3168   15.5081
   15.0602   17.0909

>> airQ_2016

airQ_2016 =

   15.3242   14.7629
   18.6536   21.8320
   18.3180   13.8826
   18.6450   19.1636
   14.2393   11.2187
   16.0711   18.4301
   15.4110   13.8512
   16.4883   18.8854
   16.3412   17.7468
   19.3424   25.3118
   11.1240   16.9534
   12.0094   24.8034

>> airQ_2017

airQ_2017 =

   12.7493   15.6095
   17.9645   25.5990
   17.1852   17.7621
   21.9838   30.3646
   12.1749   20.1561
   18.2244   34.8602
   11.0456   13.1557
   14.6352   26.2217
   12.0893   10.4657
   18.3620   15.4912
   10.9695   10.9116
   14.8427   16.1146

>> airQ_2018

airQ_2018 =

   15.3788   16.4776
   17.5721   28.0599
   16.8422   18.4897
   17.9144   27.5079
   12.7003   19.7597
   18.9284   19.0304
   12.5745   13.1946
   15.7553   19.8073
   12.4759   22.5577
   15.2807   22.8239
   11.7530   18.3440
   16.0833   26.7018
```

It is possible that I can implement the figure using matlab?
I was thinking of using probably plotly in matlab or other function.
I've also tried create one figure, hold on the figure and create another one, but my method seems incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotting 3D bars over a grid in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895354/plotting-3d-bars-over-a-grid-in-matlab)? And this kind of 3D bar plot is a terrible visualisation of data (a 3D stacked bar plot in a single line is bad enough, but this actively covers up information as well).

Comment: Hi David, thank you so much for that, it fix my problem. However, in that code, I don't know how to set the width and space between bars. I need to use this visualisation because I need to show data in 2 different variable, so that 2D ploting may not be satifying.

Comment: If you have data depending on 2 variables, use a mesh/surface plot. What you are trying to plot will just hide data and be unreadable. You really shouldn't do this if you want to actually make a plot that is useful.